# Iterate through dictionary maintaining order from constructed list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list port_ids, which are in right order. Based on that I fetch the value from a file and store it in a dictionary. But the stored values in the dictionary are not aligned with the original list. This is my code:

```
import os
os.chdir('/var/lib/docker/volumes/kolla_logs/_data/openvswitch/')
port_ids=['qvoee855b93-ba', 'qvo9aa3a7d8-64', 'qvo2fc6e482-aa', 'qvo6a27cf40-8f']

def port_numb(text):
    try:
        with open('ovs-vswitchd.log') as f:
            for line in f:
                if line.find(text) != -1:
                    return line[97:100]
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Failed to open file {}'.format(ex))

ovs_port_numb = list(map(port_numb, port_ids))
d = dict(zip(port_ids, ovs_port_numb))
print d
```

OUTPUT:
*{'qvoee855b93-ba': '174', 'qvo2fc6e482-aa': '176', 'qvo6a27cf40-8f': '177', 'qvo9aa3a7d8-64': '175'}*

I want the keys of the dictionary to be in the same order like in the list (port_ids).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key  has some good tips, something along the lines of OrderedDict should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Answer (score 0):

In Python below version 3.6, the order of keys in dictionaries is not guaranteed. If you want such behavior you have to use Python 3.6 or `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module as well shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key) as suggested by [sniperd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143387/sniperd)

Comment: Thanks for quick response.Sorry i forgot to mention i am using python2.7 and my whole setup is running on this version. Therefore, i have to use 2.7. Do you think OrderedDict can work in python2.7?

Comment: Yes, OrderedDict is available in Python 2.7 https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Even in 3.6 they advise you not to rely on the dictionary order, and if you need an order dictionary you should still be using OrderedDict.

Comment: My case is little different. I need the dict key to have exactly the same order of list(ports_ids) rather than ascending or alphabetically.

Comment: "An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted." I don't see how that is not what you need.